# Tableau and SQL Server 2012 Database Connectivity Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, tableau-api

I am attempting to link my SQL Server 2012 created database to Tableau 2018.1.  Once I establish a connection between Tableau and the Server, the only databases available are the System databases.  The databases I have created are now showing in Tableau from the drop-down list.  I'm just trying to figure out what am I doing incorrect or missing.  Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Make sure that the user you are using on Tableau's connection has enough privileges to the new databases you are creating. On SSMS, go to Security, Logins, right click your login and check if is has a User Mapping to your new database, or a generic Server Role like sysadmin.

Comment: Check the user settings and appears to be mapped correctly.  However, what I've found is that my databases are outside of where the system databases sit.  Perhaps, there is a way to move the databases to where the system databases are.

Comment: There is no "place" for the databases, and user databases are always shown separately from the system databases in SSMS if that's what you mean. Try connecting to your SQL Server instance through using the same login as the one from Tabealu but from SSMS and see which databases you can query.

Comment: @EzellFranklin , what driver are you using? An ODBC driver or the Microsft SQL Driver provided from tableau. Might want to check if you installed correctly